# jquery mobile theme or css

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-mobile, wordpress-theming

I've been tinking around w/the Jquery Mobile themeroller and I have a few questions I couldn't find answers to.  After I'm doing tinkering w/the themeroller and download my zip file, I see the CSS file in there.

Is that CSS file my actual theme in my mobile wordpress site?  I know the zip file isn't something I can simply upload into my wordpress and it'll be a theme.

What do I do w/that CSS file? Not sure where it goes.  Right now, as my theme, I have some plain old generic jquery mobile theme I found online.  Since it gave me no options to customize, I used the themeroller.  I'm just not sure what do with that CSS file...

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your Wordpress theme uses jQuery Mobile?

Comment: I have a mobile detector plugin installed and I have this theme installed:  http://www.mobilizetoday.com/freebies/jqmobile  That theme gives me no options.  So, I'm tinkering w/the themeroller to make a new look n' feel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. Simply unzip the file and plunk the CSS in your site. Then you have to LINK or IMPORT it to your HTML document.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css"/>
```

Here is the ilne you would include in your header if your folder was named 'css' and the file named 'custom.css'.

CSS works on the basis of priorities. That is, you want this CSS file to be loaded AFTER the other files. Also, be specific in your CSS selectors or use !important to designate priority.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you!  A little tidbit I didn't know, but now I do and it works great.  Just pop that in my header.php and refresh, and I see the new CSS changes.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery Mobile Wordpress theme](http://www.mobilizetoday.com/freebies/jqmobile) that you are using has a new Wordpress admin options that allow you to easily setup new themes.  Just log into your Wordpress administration area and upload your theme.  The system ships with a few jQuery Mobile themes (Velencia, Green, Default).

Here's the exact steps that they give.

> Upload Scheme: Optionally you may create your own color scheme using
>   ThemeRoller Mobile. Once your custom scheme is created and downloaded
>   you may upload it [on the Admin page] by clicking "Upload" button.

Comment: Unfortunately, that upload feature doesn't work and I've notified the developer (pending reply).  But let's say I use a different them - a blank theme for example, that's been setup for jquery mobile.  What would I do w/my CSS file from themeroller then?